# Set bearer token with OpenApi Generator

Tags: openapi-generator

I'm using OpenApiGenerator v5.0 beta csharp-netcore.  The configuration has ApiKeyPrefix and ApiKey, both of which are Dictionary<string, string>.  It seems that the token used is

`ApiKeyPrefix["Authorization"] + " " + ApiKey["Authorization"]`

Is there a way to choose which token to use?  I see Configuration.GetApiKeyWithPrefix takes a string which enables me to choose which key to inspect, but I don't see a way to choose which key to use in an individual request.

Answer (score 0):

I got so carried away looking at the source code and intellisense I forgot that I can just look in the generated code in my own project.  I can see that the choice to use the prefix and token identified by the "authorization" key is indeed hard coded.  I'll have to either edit the generated code or request a change on the OpenApi Generator repo.